# get last element in URL(menu item) generated by hook_menu

Tags: 7, uri, routes

I have created a URL/menu item via hook_menu, and in the proprocess_html I'd like to get my item (last element in the URL) (/test) without using arg(0).

I can do it in PHP but I was wondering how it was possible to get this with drupal.

```
end(explode("/", request_uri()))
```

this code is actually bad, there could be URL such as ?test=ok

Cheers,

Comment: Why not using arg() ?

Comment: let's say that on different branches I have a / more in the url so arg(0) become arg(1)

Comment: Do you know if your item is going to change ? like is it always going to be "test" ?

Comment: Yes it will be always the same last argument in the URI http://%/%/%/test

Comment: When talkin about the / more is it because of the installation path ?

Comment: yes it's something like http://myWebsite/main and the other one is http://myWebsite

Comment: I think arg() only starts where drupal is installed so it should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_pop(arg());
```

will return the last component of the current Drupal path.